# Best Tool for Mockup to CSS?

Tags: css, dreamweaver, mockups, paint.net

I've been using Paint.NET to create mockups for my web application.  They're pretty, and it's not hard to save the constituent graphical elements.  However, the process of getting my layout into CSS is completely manual and time-consuming.

I'm aware there are better tools out there for this.  Should I be looking at DreamWeaver?  I'm not looking for any auto-generated web or data access functionality, and I'm happy to code all the behavior myself.  I'm mostly looking for a great-looking layout editor that understands both layered imaging and CSS.  (Preferably, one that can map a layered image to HTML and generate initial CSS with the right styling.)

Thanks in advance for any and all insight!

Jeff

Answer (score 6):

A text editor, *really*.

It's time consuming, yes, but so is doing anything right.  I have yet to use any program that builds the design of a website with a level of markup quality that I find even remotely acceptable.  Where you may give a div a class of `userInfo`, most layout programs might give that div a class of `style12` or something equally unhelpful.  This results in unmaintainable markup, which is especially hard to build into a web application.

So learn how to do it by hand, and then do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Axuer can be used to take mockups/prototypes and export as HTML/CSS: http://www.axure.com/
I only ever used it for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

There are no apps that will make it a css3, they apps that exist will give you a lot of image sprites and css2 and a lot of bugs you have to fix manually :/
So suggest coding it manually or hiring someone who does it(Kinda cheap these days even I would do it if I get paid well enough)